# why every port on windows closed after connected to vpn?

Tags: vpn, pptp

I have windows 10, and pptpd server on ubuntu somewhere else. I also have port 3389 open on my Windows 10 machine.

after connected to VPN, Windows 10 closes my RDP connection. Testing with [yougetsignal](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/), port 3389 is now closed. 
Why? and is there any fix?

Comment: You can’t route all your internet traffic through a VPN and still receive connections to port 3389. Unless you do so using the remote VPN network. What you need is split-tunneling. Your use case is not clear, so you’ll have to decide if that is a configuration you want to use or not.

Comment: @Appleoddity: Or unless you use policy routing / source-based routing, and I was somewhat sure Windows automatically supported the latter; i.e. selecting the correct route depending on which address it needs to send a reply _from_. (But even if that's true then it's not exposed in any other way than "it magically works"... Oh well.)